# Split data across stacks in Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have the following series for column chart in Highcharts:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Skill 1',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'Target Capacity'
},{
    name: 'Skill 1',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'Actual Capacity'
},

{
    name: 'Skill 2',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'Target Capacity'
},{
    name: 'Skill 2',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'Actual Capacity'
},

{
    name: 'Skill 3',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'Target Capacity'
},{
    name: 'Skill 3',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    stack: 'Actual Capacity'
}]
```

Which produces this:

[image]

So basically the idea is to have two stacks per day (Target Capacity and Actual Capacity) of Skills 1, 2 and 3. However to achieve the two stacks per day, I have had to duplicate the skills. I could hide the second skills from the legend and keep the colors the same... but this isn't what I want ideally!

Is it possible to only have three sets of data, but split the data across stacks?

Comment: Any way you look at it, you're talking about 2 different data series for each skill. I can't see any way that it would work trying to make them one series instead. You're not duplicating any actual data series - just the name.  The "normal" way to do this is to use the *linkedTo* property to combine the series into one legend entry.

Comment: @jlbriggs `linkedTo` solves it perfectly! Thanks.